# Loading images to UITableViewCell and rounding corners using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, alamofireimage

`Alamofire` has a very convenient method to load images directly from a URL as a UIImageView extension.

```
cell.avatarImageView.af_setImageWithURL(downloadURL)
```

I'd also like to round the corners of the image. `AlamofireImage` has a method to do this as well (it's a UIImage extension),

```
image.af_imageRoundedIntoCircle()
```

However is there a way to use both of these methods at once? First method directly calls on `UIImageView` not `UIImage` so I'm unable to use it.

If I call something like this just after the  `af_setImageWithURL` call,

```
cell.avatarImageView.image = cell.avatarImageView.image?.af_imageRoundedIntoCircle()
```

It works only when tableView cells are redrawing. It has no effect on already visible cells.

Are there any other methods to achieve this? or Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why not just make the imageView rounded itself (not the image)?

Comment: yeah that's true. But I want to know how above methods can be used together without changing the imageView cornerRadius.

Comment: that is my exact question. any update ? thanks.

Comment: @EyalBenYehuda I had to manually do it without using `AlamofireImage`'s method.

Comment: Thanks, i also ended up with rounding the ImageView: cell.myUIImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myUIImageView.frame.width / 2

Answer (score 3):

yes, there is a method for that:

```
public func af_setImage(
        withURLRequest urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible,
        placeholderImage: UIImage? = nil,
        filter: ImageFilter? = nil,
        progress: ImageDownloader.ProgressHandler? = nil,
        progressQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main,
        imageTransition: ImageTransition = .noTransition,
        runImageTransitionIfCached: Bool = false,
        completion: ((DataResponse<UIImage>) -> Void)? = nil)
```

You should specify `CircleFilter()` as `filter` parameter for circular image view or `RoundedCornersFilter(radius: CGFloat, divideRadiusByImageScale: Bool)` if you would like to have rounded corners